# Fastest way to query whether a multipolygon contains a single point

Tags: postgis, latitude-longitude

I have a multipolygon of geography type (`multi_bounds`) and a point. I'm trying to figure out the fastest way to query whether the multipolygon contains the point. In this case if the point is part of the boundary it should still return true.

I've tried CoveredBy:

`WHERE ST_CoveredBy(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(:long, :lat), 4326),
      multi_bounds::geometry)`

Where `:long` and `:lat` are arguments provided by yesql.

And I've tried contains:

`WHERE ST_Contains(multi_bounds::geometry, 
      ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(:long, :lat), 4326))`

I don't see a noticeable difference and I'm wondering what the best practice is here.

I did try `ST_CoveredBy` without casting `multi_bounds` to geometry but I couldn't get past an error:

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: BOOM! Could not generate outside point!`

Comment: Does St_Intersect not work?

Comment: How about casting the point to geography?

Comment: @JakubKania Yeah I tried casting the point to `geography` and leaving `multi_bounds` as is (`geography`) and got the error above.

Comment: @NateWessel That's a great idea I had been overthinking the problem a little bit. Issue now is I'm getting `ERROR: BOOM! Could not generate outside point!` with `ST_Intersect` too for some of my multipolygons.

Comment: @CodyCanning: Is it possible that's a problem with your input? I can't see why PostGIS would need to create a point to check whether a point intersects with a polygon. Creating the point is not part of the interection checking process. Perhaps your input is outside of the range of latitude and longitude values.

Comment: One of your bounds must be quite large and/or not make sense on a sphere. The geodetic point-in-poly code has to start by generating a point outside the polygon, so it can test the number of edge crossings between the candidate point and the outside point. This is equivalent to the stab-line in a cartesian calculation. If you cast everything to geometry you'll get a cartesian calculation and it should be more reliable for your inputs (if perhaps less accurate for longer edges (depending on if you really want great circle bounds or not))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

credit to Nate Wessel for the suggestion.

Adding a column `multi_bounds_geom` of geometry type and using `ST_Intersect` is *faster* than anything else I tried.